# Change size of an image loaded from URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How to modify the size of the image here?:

```js
var image = new Image();

image.src = 'http://www.ziiweb.com/images/logo.png';

image.width = 200; //this is not modifying the width of the image

$('canvas').css({
    background: 'url(' + image.src + ')'
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="200" height="100" style="border:1px solid #000000;">
</canvas>
```

Answer (score 5):

You are inserting the image as a background, so use background-size.

```js
var image = new Image();
image.src = 'http://www.ziiweb.com/images/logo.png';

$('canvas').css({
    backgroundImage: 'url(' + image.src + ')',
    backgroundSize: "100%"
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="200" height="100" style="border:1px solid #000000;">
</canvas>
```

Answer (score 2):

use an img tag which adujsts to its given size in css, or if using the background property, use         "background-size: cover;", if you want to unevenly strech the image, use "background-size: 200px 300px;"

Answer (score 0):

Try this

image.style.width = 200;

Answer (score 0):

Just play with `CSS` background properties:

```js
var image = new Image();
image.src = 'http://www.ziiweb.com/images/logo.png';
$('canvas').css({
    background: 'url(' + image.src + ') no-repeat 0% 50%',
    backgroundSize: '100%',
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="200" height="100" style="border:1px solid #000000;">
</canvas>
```

`no-repeat`, `0% 50%` to place the image vertical aligned to the middle and set the image to fit the canva's width.